# Block Requests based on UserAgents with Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, server

my website is hosted with google cloud app engine. I have an increase request amount from the same user agent. Is there a possibility to block specific incoming requests with app engine, e.g. through the app.yaml file? I don't find anything related to that in the documentation.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, but this question should be about how to do it with your framework (e.g., Flask) and not app engine.

Comment: 1) App Engine by itself cannot, but your framework probably can. 2) If you use a framework to block requests, the requests still arrive at App Engine, you are just deciding to ignore/error certain requests. 3) User Agents are voluntary information provided by clients. User Agent information can be faked easily. 4) Spend time creating a good question so that you can get good answers.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt considered that. With Flask, it can work :)